# Jquery extend deep copy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two array as follows.

```
var array1=['a','b']
var array2=['b']
```

And i have extended above both array using $.extend method.

```
var resArray=$.extend(true,array1,array2);
```

I got the output as

```
resArray=['b','b']
```

It seems odd behavior. Is it proper behavior of Jquery extend deep copy functionality?. Please explain in details.

Comment: Are you trying to concat the arrays?

Comment: $.extend merges two or more objects not array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explain the behavior if you look at [jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/). It says that the function takes objects as input parameters. So how does an array look when it is treated as an object? In you case:

```
var array1 = { 1 : 'a', 2 : 'b'}
var array2 = { 1 : 'b'}
```

If you use `jQuery.extend()` on these the atttribute `1` of `array1` will be replaced by the one of `array2`.

Comment: in my case i have josn object , that object which contains array. For eg like this. var obj1={array1:['a','b']} and var obj2={array1:['b']}. when i extend obj1 and obj2, i get the result as {array1:['b','b']}

Comment: It's the same as I wrote above. ``array1`` will be extended with the other ``array1`` which will result into the replacing of the `'a'` in the first array.